# how to use case with select statement in sql server 2000

Tags: sql, sql-server-2000

I have a table **stdmarks** with structure as below

```
pk id bigint 
marks_obtained
```

I have a select statement as below:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN marks_obtained<25 THEN marks_obtained+'*'
ELSE marks_obtained
END
```

I want to print something like **{marks_obtained}*** when marks_obtained is less than 25 and if greater than 25 only **{marks_obtained}**

When I execute the statement I get following error:

> Error converting data type varchar to bigint.

I tried converting the result to *varchar* using cast and convert but with no success
How can I fix it?

Comment: Can you explain what you tried (e.g. Show code) and explain what "no success" means (e.g. an actual error message)?

Answer (score 4):

You can do it like this: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ef9f4/4

```
select 

  i = case when i >= 1 then 
          convert(varchar(100), i) + '*'
      else
          convert(varchar(100), i)
      end 

from test;
```

Of course, you can do it like this too:

```
select 

  i = convert(varchar(100),i) + case when i >= 1 then '*' else '' end

from test;
```

---

DDL:

```
create table test
(
  i int
  );

insert into test values(1);
```

Outputs:

```
|  I |
------
| 1* |
```

Comment: @user1500383: if this answer worked and solved your problem, then you should [mark that answer as the accepted one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/153998). This is the right and polite thing to do, and it will this show your appreciation for the people who *spent their own time to help you*.

Answer (score 0):

Adding answer to a 3-year old question. I am querying an ancient MS SQL 7 database, here is what I've done using the CASE statement:

```
 CASE WHEN
        (SELECT COUNT(*)
      FROM Table1
      WHERE Table2.code = Table1.code)  > 1 
         THEN 'SET' 
      ELSE 'PIECE' END AS UnitOfProduct
```